# emacs: libotf.so missing

Tags: apt, emacs

I'm new to ubuntu and linux in general and I'm trying to install FUSE so I can install .appimage files. But when I try to install or upgrade something using apt or apt-get i get this error:
`emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libotf.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Even tho I'm quite new to linux I know what a symlink is and have noticed that both `libotf.so.1` and `libotf.so.0` are linked to `libotf.so` wich does not exist.

I got no idea how to fix this so I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Ask the packaging system which package provides `libotf.so` with the terminal command `dpkg -S libotf.so`. Install that package, and its' dependencies.

Comment: @waltinator That probably won't work if you don't have the package installed already. The command you meant to post was `apt-file search libotf.so`. You could also do a search at https://packages.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably worked out from the error message that you're missing `libotf.so`

To find out which package contains libotf.so, you can use the following:

```
apt-file search libotf.so
```

or you can search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libotf.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=kinetic&arch=any)

This shows that you need the `libotf-dev` package. Install with:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libotf-dev
```

Comment: Well, I tried it but I can't do ```sudo apt install libotf-dev``` because I get the same error ```emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libotf.so.1...```. I've also tried to install the libotf-dev via [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com) but that didn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what I did.

Thanks to [@moo](https://askubuntu.com/users/884673/moo) for showing me [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) I believe I was able to solve this for myself.

Here's what I did:

I went to [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) and searched all packages that were missing, and on the site I downloaded `liboft1` and `libm17n-0` which were missing. And using something like GDebi package installer, I installed them both, which seems to solve the problem..